# How can I use a static getter from a class and call an object and use the this keyword?

Tags: javascript, class, static, this, getter

How can I use the static getter, z(), and call an object to use the this keyword?

I suppose the method static y() does do what I am looking for.  But I'm like to figure out if I can make this work with an actual getter.

This is my code:

```js
class test {
    constructor(x, y, z) {
        this._x = x;
        this._y = y;
        this._z = z;
    }
    static get str() { return 'Some predefined value'; } // I can use this static getter.
    get x() { return this._x; } // I can use this non-static getter on a class instance and use the this keyword (obviously).
    static y() { return this._y; } // I can use this static method on a class instance using the this keyword.
    static get z() { return this._z; } // How can I use this on class instances?.
}

const obj = new test(2, 3, 4);

console.log(test.str); // Use static getter from class.
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj).constructor.str);  // Use static getter from object instance.
console.log(obj.x); // Use non-static getter and use the this keyword.
console.log(test.y.call(obj));  // Use static method and use the this keyword.
```

Comment: `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(test, 'z').get.call(obj)`

Comment: This works!  If you post it as an answer I can mark it as a solution.

Comment: @AdamSassano: actually, just discovered a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To invoke a getter indirectly, you can use `Reflect.get` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/get)) with the third argument set to "this" object. The third argument to `Reflect.get` is

> the value of this provided for the call to target if a getter is encountered.

Example:

```js
class test {
    constructor(x, y, z) {
        this._z = z;
    }

    static get z() {
        return this._z;
    }
}

const obj = new test(2, 3, 4);

result = Reflect.get(test, 'z', obj)
console.log(result)
```

(As a side note, I hope your question is pure curiosity and you're not going to use this in production code).